# Отправка фото и текста-гиперссылки в одном сообщении (ТГ бот)

Tags: python, aiogram

Необходимо отправить фотографию и гиперссылку(текст),  в одном сообщении.
Бот выдает вместо необходимого:

текст гиперссылки(сама ссылка).
Сама строчка выглядит так:

await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, photo, caption= 'текст гиперссылки (ссылка)')

Решено!
Товарищу MyZik - спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример из [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style):

`[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)`

И не забудьте указать parse_mode:

```py
from telegram import ParseMode

...

await bot.send_photo(XXXXXXXXXXX, photo, caption='[текст гиперссылки](ссылка)', parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
```